# Is 'all' an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, predeterminers

In the following sentence, is 'all' an adjective? If yes, then what kind of adjective is it?
"She could answer all the questions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a determiner, more specifically, a "predeterminer".  Determiners are a class of words that include articles.  *All* can be tacked on before an article, therefore it's known as a predeterminer.

@BillJ says it's an adverb, but things that modify nouns are generally known as adjectives.

Comment: "Almost" is actually an adverb functioning as an external modifier.

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary thinks it's a predeterminer.... https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all

Comment: Apologies: for some reason I was reading it as “almost”, not “all”. Predeterminers (aka external modifiers) are not determiners but modifiers. They may consist of adverbs like "almost", "even", “only" etc.' as well as determinatives like “all". “All" is a quantificational expression; it's not an adjective because it doesn't denote a property of the noun.

Comment: Thank you. I do have some confusion regarding determiners and adjectives. They seem to be overlapping categories in many grammar sources. Possessive adjectives, interrogative adjectives, demonstrative adjectives, and adjectives of quality, quantity and number are kinds of adjectives. But all of these (except adjectives of quality) + articles also make up the category of determiners.
Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Articles modify nouns, so very technically articles/determiners are adjectives, but articles/determiners have restrictions that many adjectives do not.  For example, they can only precede a noun and must precede all other modifiers before the noun.  The classic English 8-parts-of-speech-model (n/v/adj/adv/pron/prep/conj/interj), while useful, doesn't always map to certain structures/uses in English nicely.  I believe modern advanced grammar study (e.g. CGEL) sort of breaks away from that rigid classification system.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!